# Spring: Status 405. Request method 'POST' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-status-code-405

I send from form an action to

```
<form name='recoverForm' action="<c:url value='recover'/>" method='POST'>
```

spring:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "recover")
public class RecoverController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String recoverPage(Map<String, Object> model) {
        return "recover"; //this works
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String recover(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("_____________recover in action");
        return "home"; //error 405
    }
```

But I get error 405 - Request method 'POST' not supported.

[image]

Why is it? i send `post request` and controller has a post method is not it?

Comment: Does your `GET` work?

Comment: @timothyclifford yes, it works

Comment: When your app is starting, can you see the POST route being mapped in the log?

Comment: @timothyclifford not sure, what do you mean

Comment: what version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @timothyclifford <org.springframework.version>4.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>

Comment: how are you building and deploying your application?

Comment: @thinker  Are you using spring security with <csrf />? if yes then use this <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>

Comment: @David I use it in `spring-sequrity.xml`

Comment: @David it helped, thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Spring-security.xml `<csrf />` : Spring Security Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF) protection blocks it.

Token required along with form via POST request.

In form add the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
```

Comment: not in` spring-sequrity.xml` but in `form` in the page